# How to Implement UIProgressView in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, uiprogressview

I have this code in a button click `[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(spinBegininapp) toTarget:self withObject:nil];` to show a activity indicator for user that the background thread is running ,i put this code to enable the activity-indicator

```
- (void)spinBegininapp
{
    _activityindictor.hidden = NO;

}
```

and it works fine,when i click the button it shows the activity-indictor animating ,when the thread goes it hides the activity-indicator,but my need is to show a progressView instead of activity-indicator,it progresses according to the thread,and if the thread finishes it need to reach progress completely and self hide.is that possible .

Answer (score 6):

```
#pragma mark - Loading Progress

static float progress = 0.0f;

-(IBAction)showWithProgress:(id)sender {
   progress = 0.0f;
   _progressView.progress = progress;
   [self performSelector:@selector(increaseProgress) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
}

-(void)increaseProgress {
   progress+=0.1f;
   _progressView.progress = progress;    
   if(progress < 1.0f)
     [self performSelector:@selector(increaseProgress) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
   else
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismiss) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2f];
}

-(void)dismiss {
   [self progressCompleted];
}
```

now call the following function whenever/where ever you want to show progress

```
[self showWithProgress:nil];
```

progress range lies between 0.0 and 1.0

1.0 means 100%

Comment: How to automatically update the progress with out IBAction,because I am downloading from server and I want to show its progress

Comment: Here is my [code](http://pastebin.com/QU7r1k7D) ,the progress bar updates only once,i.e. shows 10% and it stops

Answer (score 3):

you can add a progress view no doubt but usually it used for definite quantities like time or data.. for eg. If you are downloading a 2mb file then you can always tell how much  data you have downloaded and show the in the progress view as a factor. So if something similar is happening inside your thread you can use this..

```
UIProgressView *progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:whateverStyle];
    progressView.progress = 0.75f;
    [self.view addSubview: progressView]
    [progressView release];
```

you just need to update your progress as the value changes.... hoping this helps.

Comment: yes u r correct,i struck here for update my progress as the value changes.i put this code but no luck filepercentage = (float)1/(float)10;
 progressview.progress = filepercentage;
 
 int p = 100 *filepercentage;
    NSString *percent = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d %%",p];

Comment: "filepercentage = (float)1/(float)10" what are you doing here? and exactly what error are you facing...?

Comment: is the progressview visible? and if yes how often do you update the progressview?

Comment: no its not visible,but when the thered goes on it will visible.but no update of progress